# Trying to plot the same variable from the same group on multiple dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have multiple dataframes, each one represents one quarter of the year . so data2019q1 is one, data2019q2 is another and so on. They show the group of people and their average income. So White is a variable, Male is another one and then the average income for that group. It looks like this :

[image]

I need to use the meanIncome as the Y, time as X and the multiple groups ( White, Male) as different lines in this graph. An example would be (I am not providing dput as it does not work properly from what i tried) -> `5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("NORTE", "NORDESTE", "SUDESTE",  "SUL", "CENTROOESTE"), class = "factor"), V2007 = c("1",  "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",  "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",`  
:[image]

Also, how do i break a dataframe by one variable? I'd like to create the graphs by region, which is the UF variable.
Even if the data being in a print makes it harder, please help.
I have no clue whatsoever on how to even start the code.

Comment: Hello Lelleo, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, please provide a reproducible example rather than an image. 
Furthermore, please let us know which is the variable that maps to time. I can't figure it from your image.

Comment: There is no variable that would be time. Instead its multiple dataframes, each one is one quarter. So i have like data2019q1, data2019q2. I can't figure out a reproducible example using datasets package, so thats why I didnt provide one.  I imagine it being like dataframe1$meanIncome of is (x,y) (1, meanIncome), dataframe2 is (2, meanIncome) and so on. Each line would represent one group, and ggplot would have to link those groups i believe, so that it makes the line of only its own group , which is something i have no clue on how to do.

Comment: The easiest way seems to me  to produce a summary from each one of your dataframes, and then bind those summaries into a  single dataframe, and then plot it into ggplot. Bind those dfs with `rbind` from base or `bind_rows` from dplyr.

Comment: I don't understand your shown example. What is this supposed to be? And why does `dput(head(NameOfYourDataFrame))` not work?

Comment: Perhaps due to the dataframe being a lot of fct_collapses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With made-up data because the OP does not provide a reproducible example.
With `tidyverse`, try:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Simulating 3 tables

data2019q1 <- 
  tibble(
    UF = c("SUDESTE", "SUDESTE", "NORTE", "NORTE"),
    gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M"),
    color = c("Green", "Green", "Blue", "Blue"),
    mean_income = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 100 ))

data2019q2 <- tibble( UF = c("SUDESTE", "SUDESTE", "NORTE", "NORTE"), gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M"), color = c("Green", "Green", "Blue", "Blue"),    mean_income = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 100 ))    
data2019q3 <- tibble( UF = c("SUDESTE", "SUDESTE", "NORTE", "NORTE"), gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M"), color = c("Green", "Green", "Blue", "Blue"),    mean_income = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 100 )) 
data2019q4 <- tibble( UF = c("SUDESTE", "SUDESTE", "NORTE", "NORTE"), gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M"), color = c("Green", "Green", "Blue", "Blue"),    mean_income = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 100 ))


# Adding the period signal to the tables from their titles. You might want to create a function for this if you have many dfs.
data2019q1$period <- "data2019q1"
data2019q2$period <- "data2019q2"
data2019q3$period <- "data2019q3"
data2019q4$period <- "data2019q4"

# Binding the tables together to get "tidy" or "long" data, required for ggplot

df_binded <- 
  do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^data"))) %>% # This do.call + mget is usefull if you have a lot of tables
  mutate(gender_color = paste(gender, color, sep = " "))

df_binded %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = period, y = mean_income, group = gender_color, colour = gender_color)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ UF)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked very nicely! I wasnt using  ```sep``` which  made it not work but i added it just for the fun of it and it worked! thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is get your data in "tidy format". Since you are using `ggplot`, I would recommend you use the other packages written by the same author/group, collectively known as `tidyverse`. There are several packages all with excellent functions, `ggplot` and `dplyr` included. You will probably want to review the `dplyr` [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf). The `tidyverse`'s authors [book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html) is also an excellent resource.

I can't replicate your example data, so I'm going to create some of my own. You should always provide minimal example data. I'm using `expand_grid` which is another `tidyverse` function. You will want to use the `select` and `filter` functions to get and rename just the data you want from the respective data frames.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Creating dummy data
races <-  c("white", "asian", "latinx")
genders <-  c("male", "female", "non-binary")
data2019q1 <- expand_grid(races, genders) %>%
  mutate(meanIncome = runif(nrow(.), 50000, 150000))

data2019q2 <- expand_grid(races, genders) %>%
  mutate(meanIncome = runif(nrow(.), 50000, 150000))
```

Now you want to stack your data so it's all in the same data frame (or tibble in `tidyverse`). I'm also using `lubridate` which is part of the `tidyverse` but needs to be loaded separately.

```
library(lubridate)
data2019q1 <- data2019q1 %>%
  mutate(date = yq("2019-q1"))
data2019q2 <- data2019q2 %>%
  mutate(date = yq("2019-q2"))
plot_data <- bind_rows(data2019q1, data2019q2)
```

Now you can use `ggplot`. Check out it's [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/data-visualization-2.1.pdf) too. You may consider using different aesthetics for the different groups, or just combine all the groups (using `unite`) and color.

```
ggplot(data = plot_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = meanIncome, color = genders, linetype = races))
plot_data %>%
  unite(groups, races, genders) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = meanIncome, color = groups))
```

[image]

Good luck. And please provide better reproducible data in the future. My bottom line advice is read and practice the book first.